# SQL Category Name Tree Query - no write access

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, category-tree

I need to query our Magento 1.9 installation for a list of category names with full parent/child paths - this is not the request path, I mean the full branch from the category name tree. I've seen a few solutions but they seem to rely on temp tables. I only have read access to our install at the moment. Anyone have an alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

With your updated question the query is more complicated but it works:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE explode( pDelim VARCHAR(32), pStr TEXT)                                
BEGIN                                
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_explode;                                
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_explode (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(40));                                
  SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_explode (word) VALUES (', REPLACE(QUOTE(pStr), pDelim, '\'), (\''), ')');                                
  PREPARE myStmt FROM @sql;                                
  EXECUTE myStmt;                                
END |   

DELIMITER ;

set @str = (select path from catalog_category_flat_store_1 where entity_id = 3);
call explode('/', @str);

select GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '/') from catalog_category_flat_store_1 where entity_id in (SELECT id FROM temp_explode);
```

Notice that I create a procedure since MySQL doesn't have a native explode function. Also I used a hard coded category id as an example (3)  you can replace it for your category id.

Finally I'm using flat tables but you can achieve the same joining more tables if you want to use EAV model.

**OLD ANSWER**

You can get the category path from the core_url_rewrite table with a query like this:

```
select request_path from core_url_rewrite where category_id is not null;
```

If you want you can also get the target_path like this:

```
select request_path, target_path from core_url_rewrite where category_id is not null;
```

Comment: thanks very much for that - I voted you up, but I don't have the rep for that to be public yet! I actually realise I have phrased my question incorrectly - what I actually need is the category names in a path format rather than the request path itself, if that makes sense

Comment: @BillDavies I updated my answer, tested locally and works. Please accept the answer

Comment: Marked you up again, but as per original question, I can't use temp tables, no write access! Thank you very much though!